# Why does the Partners website think that my Salesforce Dev org lacks packages?

Tags: managed-package, partner-portal

I spent the last 3 months developing a managed package, as part of my developer organization.

Then I went here:

https://partners.salesforce.com/

I signed up and I got approved.

Now I go here:

https://partners.salesforce.com/publisherOrgs

I click "Connect Organizations". They ask for a username and password. I give the Username and Password of my developer organization. The site correctly imports the Organization, but says it has zero packages.

And yet if I go here:

https://na35.salesforce.com/03341000000B9b4?tab=PackageComponents

I can see my package, which is marked "managed".

What else do I need to do so the Partners site sees the managed package?

We want to release this managed package in the Salesforce app store.

Comment: Have you uploaded the package ?You will need to click upload and generate a managed package BETA version .What version is your manage package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like unless you upload the package and either generate a BETA or a released version for managed package or a valid version for unmanaged package ,they do not appear .

Strongly recommend that you click on the upload button and generate a version and then it should appear in your organisation in publisher console .

Comment: Where is the upload button? I created a "managed package" as part of my developer account. How do I transform that into a BETA?

Comment: I created a managed package, but when I look under the "Versions" tab, it says "No versions uploaded"

Comment: Did you upload it and get the package link ?